# Word Counting Program in C

Tags: c

I am referring K and R book for learning C;
It is regarding while loop with EOF in Word counting program, the program given in the book runs fine, but i want to know how it stop taking input after just one enter and gives the output with line, word, & character count. Before this program, I used to press Ctrl + Z followed by enter to get output wherever while loop with !=EOF was used.

Please help me in understanding what exactly happened in this program to break loop.

Attaching the Code and output  -

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define IN 1            /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0           /* outside a word */

/* count lines, words, and charaters in input */

main()
{
    int c, n1, nw, nc, state; /* n1 for line count, nw for word count, & nc for character count */

    state = OUT;
    n1 = nw = nc = 0;
    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF ){

    ++nc;
    if ( c == '\n')
    ++n1;
    if ( c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
    state = OUT;
    else if ( state == OUT) {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
    }
    printf ( "%d %d %d \n", n1, nw, nc);

    }
}
```

Output-
[image]

Comment: Run in a debugger, step through the code line by line. That will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: try moving the printf out side the while loop.

Comment: Tip: There is no need to make a screenshot of *console* output. Just copy the literal text into your post.

Comment: Thanks @ Jongware will take care next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop hasn't ended. You can verify this be typing in some more characters and pressing enter. You'll see more output. It is because this `printf`:

```
printf ( "%d %d %d \n", n1, nw, nc);
```

is *in* the loop. It'll be executed in every iteration of the loop.

---

If you want the output to be seen *after* you send `EOF` using <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, move the `printf` outside the loop.

Comment: but after pressing enter it doesn't allow me to give further inputs, the program run and increases it count, and further more as i press Ctrl + Z the output window get close.

Comment: You can't input any more characters? That's odd. The window closes probably because you don't have some function to make the console window stay open. You can use `getch()` at the end, just before the `}` of `main` to tackle this problem.

Comment: thanks @ Cool guy, after removing the printf from the loop, it allowed me to put more characters as input.

Comment: Thanks, I understood what happen exactly- printf was in while loop so as I put any characters as input, it will directly run, the condition and give output for each character, than it waits for further input to get new characters and start counting from where it was stopped.

Comment: @Vino , Exactly. Glad you've understood it. :-)